# Windows 8 IAP Receipt handling server side & consumables?

Tags: windows-8, in-app-purchase, receipt

I am implementing a simple server-side verification for Windows 8 IAPs and I'm slightly baffled on how to handle this. Basically what I do know is I verify the receipt using the code that was included in the example 
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/windows/apps/jj649137.aspx

In the example, there is a AppReceipt and ProductReceipt. If I understood it correctly, having a simple IAP to buy, for example, gold in the game, I am only interested in the ProductReceipt. However, I don't understand why "AppReceipt" is included here at all. Is the initial app purchase always included in the receipt or is it an optional field?

So an unified way of making sure the user cannot "cash in" the same receipt twice would simply to save the ProductReceipt ID in the back end database? And that this would be a valid approach for both durables and consumables, of which the latter is not yet implemented?

Answer (score 0):

AppReceipt is just an example that you can ignore. In most cases game will send you receipt (ProductReceipt XML) and you will have to verify it on server side.

If you look at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8b3cf68d-897d-4a47-ace0-2c42355bf688/protecting-your-windows-store-app-from-unauthorized-use?forum=windowsstore
You will notice:

> The ID of each receipt element is unique per user (and device) and you can validate it on your server to confirm that the transaction is legitimate for that user and not a fraudulent transaction. This is especially valuable when your app has its own authentication mechanism because it allows you to validate that each user that appears to have purchased your app is, in fact, a unique customer.

So if you want to, you can extract IDs from this XML.